# Is there a javascript library for Hadoop sequencefile

Tags: javascript, node.js, hadoop, sequencefile

I try to build nodejs server which collect binary data from user and storing it to Hadoop sequencefile. As a good [tutorial](http://mojodna.net/2013/12/27/binary-streaming-with-hadoop-and-nodejs.html), there's approach using the Hadoop executable.

My question: **Is there javascript library or snippet for making Hadoop sequencefile** to make a sequencefile without Hadoop executables.

Earlier approach was based on [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) on Apache and [python-hadoop](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/Hadoop/tree/master/python-hadoop). But it's hard to control *concurrency* between Apache's processes and threads. So I'd like to move nodejs if Hadoop sequencefile library for javascript exists.